# Une nuance entre « laisser entendre » et « laisser penser »

Tags: sens

> 1 : Ne **laisse** pas **entendre que** tu es venu ici pour autre chose que pour m’en sortir.
>
> 2 : Elle vous a dit quelque chose pouvant **laisser penser que** quelqu'un lui en voulait ?

Les deux expressions ont peut-être un sens similaire, sinon le même, mais par ailleurs je me demande s’il faut forcément utiliser une personne {qqn} pour le sujet de « laisser entendre », alors que avec « laisser penser », il faut une chose {qqch}.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La différence semble* être l'intention. "*Laisser entendre*" veut dire que le locuteur essaie d'insinuer quelque chose, volontairement. "*Laisser penser*" est involontaire, et ne dépend pas de la personne qui le dit.

> Les indices laissent penser que le mari est le coupable

C'est un fait général, le total des faits semble porter vers une conclusion. Ça ne provient pas forcément d'une discussion.

> Il a laissé entendre qu'il aimerait une augmentation.

Il ne l'a pas dit, mais il l'a fait comprendre. Initialement c'est par une communication mais par figure de style ça peut s'étendre à plus de choses.

D'après [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/porter_%C3%A0_croire), "*Laisser (à) penser*" est un synonyme de "*porter à croire*", qui veut bien dire qu'un total de faits poussent vers une conclusion particulière, tandis que [laisser entendre](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/laisser_entendre) est un quasi-synonyme de "*sous-entendre*".

*(Je dis "semble" parce que  je base en partie ma réponse sur le wiktionnaire)

Comment: Oui, laisser penser se dirait en rapport avec une situation. laisser entendre se dirait par rapport à quelque chose qui a été dit, par exemple.

Answer (score 2):

Dans la première expression, « entendre » a son sens original, c'est à dire « comprendre ».

Comprendre implique d'une part qu'il y a eu un processus qui a conduit quelqu'un qui ne comprenait pas quelque chose à le comprendre, et d'autre part que la chose comprise est un fait démontrable et probablement avéré.

Penser n'implique pas qu'il y a eu un processus particulier et la chose pensée n'est pas forcément démontrable ou avérée.

> Elle m'a fait comprendre qu'il me mentait → He is lying to me.
>
> Elle m'a fait penser qu'il me mentait. → He might be lying to me.